# Print levels of a factor present within select criteria rather than all levels of the factor in R?

Tags: r

I am working with R version i386 3.1.1 and RStudio 0.99.442.

I have large datasets of tree species that I've collected from 7 plots, each of which are divided into 5 subplots (i.e. 35 distinct subplots). I am trying to get R to run through my dataset and print the species which are present within each plot.

I thought I could use "aggregate" to apply the "levels" function to the Species data column and have it return the Species present for each Plot and Subplot, however it returns the levels of the entire data frame (for 12 species, total) rather than the 3 or 4 species that are actually present in the Subplot.

To provide a reproducible example of what I'm trying to do, we can use the "warpbreaks" dataset that comes with R.

I convert the 'breaks' variable in warpbreaks to a factor variable to recreate the problem; It thus exemplifies my 'species' variable, whereas 'warpbreaks$wool' would represent 'plot', and 'warpbreaks$tension' would represent 'subplot'.

```
require(stats)
warpbreaks$breaks = as.factor(warpbreaks$breaks)
aggregate(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks, FUN="levels")
```

If we look at the warpbreaks data, then for "Plot" A (wool) and "Subplot" L (tension) - the desired script would print the species "26, 30, 54, 25, etc."

```
breaks wool tension
1      26    A       L
2      30    A       L
3      54    A       L
4      25    A       L
5      70    A       L
6      52    A       L
7      51    A       L
8      26    A       L
9      67    A       L
10     18    A       M
11     21    A       M
12     29    A       M
...
```

Instead, R returns something of this sort, where it is printing ALL of the levels of the factor variable for ALL of the plots:

```
    wool tension breaks.1 breaks.2 breaks.3 breaks.4 breaks.5 breaks... 
1    A       L       10       12       13       14       15       ...      
2    B       L       10       12       13       14       15       ...      
3    A       M       10       12       13       14       15       ...      
4    B       M       10       12       13       14       15       ...      
5    A       H       10       12       13       14       15       ...      
6    B       H       10       12       13       14       15       ...
```

How do I get it to print only the factors that are present within that Plot/Subplot combination? Am I totally off in my use of "aggregate"? I'd imagine this is a relatively easy task for an experience R user...

First time stackoverflow post - would appreciate any help or nudges towards the right code!

Many kind thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `FUN=unique` rather than `FUN=levels`. `levels` will return every level of the factor, as you have surmised already. `unique(...)` will only return the unique levels.

```
y <- aggregate(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks, FUN=unique)
  wool tension                          breaks
1    A       L  14, 18, 29, 13, 31, 28, 27, 30
2    B       L    15, 4, 17, 9, 19, 23, 10, 26
3    A       M     8, 11, 17, 7, 2, 20, 18, 21
4    B       M    24, 14, 9, 6, 22, 16, 11, 17
5    A       H 21, 11, 12, 8, 1, 25, 16, 5, 14
6    B       H      10, 11, 12, 7, 3, 5, 6, 16
```

**NOTE** the `breaks` column is a little weird, as in each row of that column instead of having one value (which makes sense for a dataframe), you have a vector of values. i.e. each cell of that `breaks` column is NOT a string; it's a vector!

```
> class(y$wool)
[1] "factor"
> class(y$breaks) # list !!
[1] "list"
> y$breaks[[1]] # first row in breaks
[1] 26 30 54 25 70 52 51 67
Levels: 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 35 36 39 41 42 43 44 51 52 54 67 70
```

Note that to access the first element of the `breaks` column, instead of doing `y$breaks[1]` (like you would with the `wool` or `tension` column) you need to do `y$breaks[[1]]` because of this.

Data frames are not really meant to work like this; a single cell in a dataframe is supposed to have a single value, and most functions will expect a dataframe to conform to this, so just keep this in mind when doing future processing.

If you wanted to convert to a string, use (e.g.) `FUN=function (x) paste(unique(x), collapse=', ')`; then `y$breaks` will be a column of strings and behaves as normal.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you - the added information is very helpful.